# Purpose of a and include keywords in SPF

Tags: email, spf, txt-record

In tutorial I found this example record for SPF, but the a and include keywords wasn't explained. I don't find accurate information about them in the internet.

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:46.16.60.0/23 a:cdmon.com include:srv.cat ~all
```

Answer (score 1):

- **"a"** keyword: This adds the IP addresses which are the A- or AAAA-Record of the same Domain. See also the RFC on the "a" mechanism: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.3

  > This mechanism matches if `<ip>` is one of the 's IP
  > addresses.  For clarity, this means the "a" mechanism also matches
  > AAAA records.
- **include** keyword: This includes the SPF record of the specified domain. The [RFC says for this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2):

  > The "include" mechanism triggers a recursive evaluation of
  > `check_host()`.
  >
  > 1. The  is expanded as per Section 7.
  > 2. check_host() is evaluated with the resulting string as the
  >    .  The  and  arguments remain the same as in
  >    the current evaluation of check_host().
  > 3. The recursive evaluation returns match, not-match, or an error.
  > 4. If it returns match, then the appropriate result for the
  >    "include" mechanism is used (e.g., include or +include produces a
  >    "pass" result and -include produces "fail").
  > 5. If it returns not-match or an error, the parent check_host()
  >    resumes processing as per the table below, with the previous
  >    value of  restored.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > The "include" mechanism makes it possible for one domain to designate
  > multiple administratively independent domains.  For example, a vanity
  > domain "example.net" might send mail using the servers of
  > administratively independent domains example.com and example.org.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break it down, segment by segment:

1. `v=spf1`: SPF version 1 (*v=version*)
2. `a`: Originates from an email server (IP) that has a corresponding [A record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/) on the domain in question.
3. `ptr`: **This is deprecated, and should not be used** - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.5
4. `ip4:46.16.60.0/23`: originates from an email server within CIDR range specificed.
5. `a:cdmon.com`: originates from an email server (IP) that has a corresponding A record on the specified zone (cdmon.com).
6. `include:srv.cat`: includes the SPF record from the specified zone/record.
7. `~all`: this instructs email servers to 'softfail' if SPF does not pass (a condition specified is not met)

Comment: How can you interprete srv.cat as zone/record? What other values are allowed here?

Comment: The mail server will essentially do a DNS lookup for an SPF (TXT) record at the specified location, any FQDN with a corresponding SPF (TXT) record is valid. See RFC reference: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-5.2